# Как программно сменить Backgroung Button'a

Tags: c#, wpf

Путь к картинке 
`images/eye_opacity.png`

Как программно из xaml.cs изменить картинку кнопки?

```
<Button Margin="1200,268,20,680" RenderTransformOrigin="0.428,-0.535" Opacity="10" Click="Button_Click_1" Command="{Binding PlayCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=ButtonImage, Path=Source}">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush x:Name="name" ImageSource="images/eye.png"/>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
```

Comment: @АндрейNOP жалуется теперь на "Недопустимый URI: Невозможно определить формат URI.". Но путь указан правильный.

Comment: Спасибо, сработало!

Comment: Хорошо, оформлю ответом. Лишние комментарии давайте удалим, чтобы не засорять топик.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
name.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("путь_к_картинке"));
```

При этом следует использовать *упакованный Uri*: `pack://application:,,,/images/eye_opacity.png`